# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when posting files using HttpPostedFileBase[]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error message - Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I believe that 'files' is empty - but not sure why. Could someone tell me why files would be empty?

Thanks!

View:

```
<form type="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("AddImage", "HelpDesk")" method="post">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td style="width: 105px"><br /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width: 105px; font-weight: bold">Attach File(s):</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value=@item.ID>
    <input type="hidden" id="requesttype" name="RequestType" value=@item.RequestType>
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
 </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddImage(HelpdeskImage model, int id, string requesttype,    HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
{

    var fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
    hd.HelpdeskImages.Add(new HelpdeskImage
    {
        HelpdeskNum = id,
        DocumentExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName),
        Image = fileBytes,
        DocumentName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
        RequestType = requesttype,
        Created = DateTime.Now,
    }
    );
    hd.SaveChanges();

}

//}
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your form tag to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Specifying this type is necessary when you have an input type="file".

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("AddImage", "HelpDesk")" method="post">
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: I added that but I am still getting the same error?

Comment: @SEBTulsa I'm sorry, it's supposed to be `enctype` and not just type

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I needed.